# How to perform mapping between two entities where one must contain the other and there can be multiple relationships but 1 to 1

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

How to perform the mapping between two units "Professional" and "Agenda" where an "Agenda" must contain a "Professional" and there can be more than one "Agenda" for the same "Professional"

Entities in the application:

```
public class Profissional
{
    public GuidId Id { get; set; }

    public StatusEnum Status { get; set; }

    public string? Nome { get; set; }
}

public class ProfissionalAgenda : Profissional
{
    public GuidId AgendaId { get; set; }//Foreign key

    public virtual Agenda Agenda { get; set; } = null!;//navigation property
}

public class Agenda
{
    public GuidId Id { get; set; }

    public string NomeAgenda { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ProfissionalAgenda? Profissional { get; set; }

    public StatusEnum Status { get; set; }
}
```

With the following mapping:

```
public class ProfissionalConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Profissional>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Profissional> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
    }
}

public class AgendaConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Agenda>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Agenda> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

        builder
            .HasOne(x => x.Profissional)
            .WithOne(x => x.Agenda)
            .HasForeignKey<ProfissionalAgenda>(x => x.AgendaId);
    }
}
```

Currently, with the configuration, the generated migration was inadequate as it does not allow me to have more than one schedule for the same professional:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Profissionais](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Status] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AgendaId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL, --Wrong ownership as there may be more than one agenda with the same professional
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Profissionais] PRIMARY KEY
 )
 
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Agendas](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [NomeAgenda] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Status] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Agendas] PRIMARY KEY
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A case where a professional can be associated with many agendas and an agenda requires a professional is a many-to-one relationship. This is commonly implemented by having a non-null ProfessionalId on the Agenda table. The Professional entity can optionally have a collection of Agendas defined if you want the professional to easily access their agendas, but this is not required.

```
public class Professional
{
    [Key]
    public GuidId Id { get; set; }
    // ...

    // Optional
    public virtual ICollection<Agenda> Agendas { get; protected set; } = new List<Agenda>();
}

public class Agenda
{
    [Key]
    public GuidId Id { get; set; }
    
    // ...

    [ForeignKey("ProfessionalId")] // Shadow property or can be declared.
    public virtual Professional { get; set; }
}
```

EF can generally wire these up automatically or you can do it explicitly on the  OnModelCreating in the DbContext or via an EntityTypeConfiguration:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Agenda>()
     .HasOne(x => x.Professional)
     .WithMany(x => X.Agendas)
     .IsRequired();
```

If you don't need/want an Agendas collection exposed in the Professional:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Agenda>()
     .HasOne(x => x.Professional)
     .WithMany()
     .IsRequired();
```

Your class "ProfessionalAgenda" is not required, and would potentially confuse EF. A ProfessionalAgenda type entity/table would normally be used for a many-to-many relationship between the two tables. Essentially a table containing a ProfessionalId and AgendaId which would allow a Professional to have a collection of Agendas where each Agenda is associated with a collection of Professionals. In your example you're creating something like an inheritance model which EF can support, but would not be applicable for what you describe.

Edit: Regarding the comment:

> When I save a new Agenda that references a older Professional (that
> stored in DB) will throw any exception like:
> EntityFramework.Exceptions.Common.UniqueConstraintException: 'Unique
> constraint violation'?

When working with existing data it is important to ensure that you are linking your new records to existing, tracked references that the DbContext knows about. A common problem with web applications where code is passing Entity types between client and server is that each Request is a new DbContext instance and what you think is an Entity reference being passed in is nothing more than a deserialized block of data cast as an entity.

So a method that looks something like this:

```
public ActionResult CreateAgenda(string agendaName, Professional professional)
{
    var newAgenda = new Agenda { Name = agendaName, Professional = professional, ... };
    context.Agendas.Add(newAgenda);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

It is no different to doing something like:

```
public ActionResult CreateAgenda(string agendaName, int professionalId, string professionalName)
{
    var professional = new Professional { Id = professionalId, Name = professionalName, ... };

    var newAgenda = new Agenda { Professional = professional, ... };
    context.Agendas.Add(newAgenda);
}
```

... where the professional details reflect an existing Professional record. The DbContext isn't tracking that row so it doesn't know if it's supposed to be relating to an existing row or a new record. When it's untracked like that the DbContext will always treat it as a new row, so this can lead to either PK unique constraint violations or inserting duplicate data with a new Id.

To do this properly you have two options:

Load the related existing data from the DbContext:

```
var professional = context.Professionals.Single(x => x.Id == professionalId);

var newAgenda = new Agenda { Professional = professional, ... };
context.Agendas.Add(newAgenda);
```

This helps ensure that any passed in referenced ID actually exists. It also simplifies and reduces the size of the data coming in since anything referenced we only need to pass IDs.

Option 2: going back to existing methods like:

```
public ActionResult CreateAgenda(string agendaName, Professional professional)
```

we need to associate the passed in Professional to the DbContext so it knows to treat it as an existing row:

```
public ActionResult CreateAgenda(string agendaName, Professional professional)
{
    var existingProfessional = context.Professionals.Local.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == professional.Id);
    if (existingProfessional == null)
    {
        context.Attach(professional);
        existingProfessional = professional;
    }
    var newAgenda = new Agenda { Name = agendaName, Professional = existingProfessional, ... };
    context.Agendas.Add(newAgenda);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

You will come across examples that just attach a passed in reference, and in many cases this will work, however there will be situations where the DbContext is already tracking an entity and the Attach will fail. This can be a common case with more complex objects being passed around as **every** reference in an object graph linked to a new entity to be saved needs to be attached and you can run into situations where the same entity gets deserialized as a reference to two other references. (Think like a "Status" entity linked to each entity in a collection you want to attach) With things like deserialization these "same" entities would be given unique references with the same ID rather than a common reference so attaching the first one will work, but the second will fail. To be safe, always check the DbContext's local cache before attaching. Once an entity is attached and tracked, EF will treat it as an existing row and it can be associated to a new entity.

I Generally advise avoiding this second option, and strongly recommend NOT ever setting an attached entity's state to Modified to use this technique to try and update data without a round trip to the database. The problem with this approach compared to the first approach is that you are assuming that the data passed in still points to a valid row in the DB. It may not, and this will fail if the row happened to get deleted or such which will just end up a FK violation triggered on SaveChanges. With the first approach the exception will be on the line when we try to find the Professional so it's more clear exactly where the problem lies. Why we never want to use this with EntityState.Modified for updating is because we should never trust data coming from a client such as a web request. That data could be tampered with or have a bug due to the serialization (such as fields not coming back from a form POST) which could erase or alter data incorrectly. It's also inefficient as when you do an `entity.State = EntityState.Modified;` EF will generate an `UPDATE` SQL statement for **all** columns whether anything actually changed or not. With change tracking where you copy values across, EF will generate an `UPDATE` statement only for the values that do change, and only if at least one value does change.  If you use the second approach with attaching, use it with caution.

Comment: Thank you Steve Py for yor answer, I have a question: When I save a new Agenda that references a older Professional (that stored in DB) will throw any exception like: EntityFramework.Exceptions.Common.UniqueConstraintException: 'Unique constraint violation' ?

Comment: I have extended the answer to help explain the issue you are seeing, and how to address it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, its very good